# Kendo treeview expand UI overlapping icons

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a Kendo UI treeview which contains some node that i load children on expand by firing a ajax call and returning a data array. This works fine and i get the data and it binds to the tree.

However the issue occurs after the first expand of a node, when i expand the node first time the tree behaves correctly and everything is fine, however if i collapse and expand the node again the tree does not push the other nodes down and the expanded node overlaps all other icons in tree.

```
Expanded on first run
```

[image: Expdaded on first run]

```
Second Expand
```

[image]

This happens for all the nodes that i expand on the 2nd run.

Here is the code that i use to build the tree

```
$('#all-library-tree').kendoTreeView({
        loadOnDemand: true,
        dataSource: _masterTreeViewMasterObj.sort().reverse(), // top level nodes
        dataTextField: "text",
        expand: function (e) {
            var treeView = $('#all-library-tree').data('kendoTreeView');
            var dataItem = treeView.dataItem(e.node);
            dataItem.load();

            if (dataItem.children.data().length !== 0) return;


            if (dataItem.id === -1) {
                //get unused data children for node 
                GetUnUsedChildrenForRHSTree(dataItem.text, dataItem.children);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to fix this issue by adding dataItem.loaded("false"); just before dataItem.load(); hope this helps someone in the future.